# Copy Value From Cell Above If Cell Equals Zero

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column that returns either zero or a value `>0`.

So `A1` to `A20` could be 0 and `A10` could be 100 and `A20` could be 50.

In Column B I would like to look at Column A and do this:
`=IF(A2=0, A1, A2)`

Obviously this works but when I copy the formula down Column B, I would like it to return the value in `A10` (which is greater than zero) in Cells `B10, B11, B12` etc until it finds another Cell greater than zero, which in the example above would be `A20`.

The value in `A20` would then be copied in `B20, B21` and so on.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
=IF(A10=0,B9,A10)
```

And so on? Of course, you can't use that on the first row, so it should be something like:

```
=A1
```

Or whatever suits you.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I can't believe it was so simple! It just proves that the simplest answer is just asking someone who can't see the rest of the sheet! You know when you spend hours in and out of vba and nested If's that your brain stops working? That's where I am! Thanks for the solution!